# Digitalising a Kaplan Meier Curve in python

Tags: python, opencv, survival-analysis

I am trying to see if it is possible to add a Kaplan Meier line plot into python - detect the x and y axes, the x and y limits on those axes and, as a Kaplan Meier curve moves across the plot at right angles, to see where there are more pixels than the width of the line to determine where  there is a change and record that change. I've got the code I am working on below - but I am stumped Is it possible?

[image: Kaplan Meier curve example]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('OS.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold the image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("Threshold", thresh)

# Remove noise using morphological operations
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
cleaned = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
cleaned = cv2.morphologyEx(cleaned, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("Cleaned", cleaned)

# Detect the KM curve. Assuming it's the longest contour in the image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cleaned, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

if not contours:
    print("No contours detected!")
    exit()

km_curve = contours[0]

# Draw detected contour
img_contour = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.drawContours(img_contour, [km_curve], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Contour", img_contour)

# Extract x and y coordinates
x_vals = [pt[0][0] for pt in km_curve]
y_vals = [pt[0][1] for pt in km_curve]

# Compute derivatives
dx = np.diff(x_vals)
dy = np.diff(y_vals)

# Identify change points
change_points = []

for i in range(1, len(dx)):
    if dx[i] * dx[i-1] < 0 or dy[i] * dy[i-1] < 0:  # Sign change
        change_points.append((x_vals[i], y_vals[i]))

print(f"Detected {len(change_points)} change points")

# Draw change points on the original image
for point in change_points:
    cv2.circle(img, point, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)  # Drawing a red circle around each change point

# Display the result
cv2.imshow("Change Points", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit:

What stumps me is that I cant get 1) the location of the x and y axes to recalibrate the data, 2) i can only get a couple of the points on one curve 3) i havent been able to get the axes labels to use to  recalibrate the points (code not included above)

The only semi-relevent outcome is below however i need all points rather than a couple. Ive tried playing around with the transparency with no luck
[image]

Comment: What stumps you?